# Having issues with FFMPEG

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, cat, raspberry-pi4

Im using the following code to timelapse a set of files in the format of yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm

It is using fswebcam to make the image and does so every minute with a crontab, that works fine, however the ffmpeg isn't working, im using the following command for it

```bash
cat $(ls | sort -V) | ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i - -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 20 outputvideo.avi
```

When running the code I get a

pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input

I got this from https://youtu.be/_uVaZalaSbI to make the image creator and https://youtu.be/miYSR8yjbAM to make the video processor.

Any help would be nice, thanks.

Comment: First, try your command with a single file. Then show the output of your `ls | sort -V` command. Blindly doing a `cat` on `ls` output is probably your problem.

Comment: You could try something like this: `for f in *.jpg; do cat "$f"; done | ffmpeg -r 10 -f image2pipe -i -  ...etc`

Comment: It works with a single file, and the 'video' produced just contains that 1 frame. When running the cat $(ls | sort -V) command it just prints a whole load of unreadable files. But I will attempt your advise shortly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for mivk for helping on this, and in my case the command

```
 for f in *.jpg; do cat "$f"; done | ffmpeg -r 10 -f image2pipe -i - -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p outputvideo.avi
```

worked perfectly for me and outputted a timelapse as planned.